# Additional CRUD query in angular $resource

Tags: angularjs

I am on `django rest framework`, till now i have implemented CRUD operations on both side, but there is an additional filter query that i want implemented. The back-end has been implemented using [django-filter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-filter). How do i extend $resource for the same.

Being new to using $resource i followed [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) guide for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to extend the default set of resource actions, you can do it by passing your custom actions as the third parameter when you create a resource class object.

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), your custom actions should be created in the format of $http.config:

```
{action1: {method:?, params:?, isArray:?, headers:?, ...},
 action2: {method:?, params:?, isArray:?, headers:?, ...}
 }
```

Your final $resource declaration would look like this:

```
return $resource(url, {},
     {
         mycustommethod: { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
     }
);
```

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that you can override the URL for the resource if needed by specifying it in the list of parameters for a custom method that you specify.